# jQuery loading spinner not showing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, loading

I am developing android application and I am trying to show loading spinner while my html is being formatted, but the spinner is not showing and I have no idea why.
 Here is the code:

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("UserTeams") != null && manual == false) {
        $(window.localStorage.getItem("UserTeams")).appendTo("#listTeams");
        $("#listTeams").listview("refresh").listview();           
    }
$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

Any ideas why the spinner is not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use native functions via JavaSriptInterface to show progress.

JavaScriptInterface:

```
private final class JavaScriptInterface {

    public JavaScriptInterface() {
    }

    /* progressDialog is a field of Your Activity.
       JavaScriptInterface is internal class of Your Activity. */

    public void showDialog() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getString(R.string.common_loading_upper));
            }
        }
    }

    public void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }  
    }
}
```

Register JavaScriptInterface:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "myinterface");
```

JavaScript code to call dialog:

```
window.myinterface.showDialog();
```